# Keep getting HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error when trying to POST form data with Flask

Tags: python, html, http, flask, web

I am trying to capture HTTP form data using Python and Flask, but I keep getting "method not allowed" error. I have been trying to figure out why for some time with no luck. **Here is what my code looks like:**

```html
@app.route("/add_recipe")  
  def addrecipepage():
    if request.method=="post":
        print ("Successful post request") # Just testing if code is working so far
    return render_template("add_recipe.html")
```

**and the HTML code:**

```html
<form id="contact" action="browseAll" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <fieldset>
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Recipe Name..." required="">
        </fieldset>

<div class="col-12">
    <textarea name="demo-message" id="recipeText" placeholder="Enter Ingredients & Instructions Here" rows="15"></textarea>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button">Add The Recipe!</button>
    <button id="uploadPhotoButton">Upload A Photo!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button, I get a HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error. Anybody have any ideas as to why after looking at this? "browseAll" is another HTML page that I created an endpoint for in my app.py file. The same error gets thrown even if I don't specify an action though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a POST (your form has method = "post") but your route does not have a `post` method attached to it. When you define a route without attaching a method, it defaults to `GET`. You need to do this

```
@app.route("/add_recipe", methods =['GET', 'POST'])
```